# How to fix pink tiles when there is a problem with the Shader?

Tags: unity, tilemap, palette

Because of some dumb mistake I did **fifth** time, I had to repaint my level in my 2D game.
The problem is that the tiles I use from the `Tile Palette` turn into pink because of some shader error. I came to this conclusion after a long time of browsing through the forums.

I am 100% sure that this will happen again, because I don't know what causes this behavior. So, prevention is not an option for me.
*What is the solution?*

By @DMGregory's suggestion, I was able to recreate this dumb behavior of mine in an empty project.
What I do is dragging and dropping a tileset onto a tile palette which I am using, and then **overwriting** the current tile palette. Then, the former assets are lost (I guess?) leaving me with pink tiles.

Attached picture is one of my levels created using `Tile Palette`. How do I take this back? I don't want to repaint my level everytime I do whatever that causes this behavior.
[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the specific steps required to reproduce this problem? The various shades of pink shown here doesn't look like the standard single-shade magenta for a shader that failed to compile, so more details on how to trigger this or what kinds of console output accompany it would help us narrow down and test potential solutions.

Comment: I think it happens everytime I try to create a new Tile Palette, but I'm not sure. I'll add this comment as an edit to the post.

Comment: Try reproducing the problem in a new empty project by following those steps. If they succeed in reproducing the issue, post those steps as part of your question.

Comment: @DMGregory I could reproduce the error! Please see the edit.